# What word or words to call a pregnant lady who is giving birth soon?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

What word or words to describe or call a pregnant lady who is giving birth soon? Or anytime within a week, month or day?

I was thinking *expectant* but it turns out it just means pregnant.

Comment: Formal or informal?  Informally, "very pregnant" (with "very" emphasized) is often used to describe a woman in the last month or so of pregnancy.

Comment: **Due Anyday now**

Is they way I normally hear it put.

sometimes even shortened to "due" by iteself

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd go with [***parturient***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/parturient?s=t): literally, "about to give birth".  The derivation is from Latin, where it literally meant "in labor" - but the current meaning is a little less immediate.

Comment: But who in the world uses it? Doctors perhaps? I wouldn't know what it meant if I heard it.